# Solve equation $\lfloor\arcsin x\rfloor+\lfloor\arccos x\rfloor+\lfloor\arctan x\rfloor=\ln x$

Tags: trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Solve over reals: $$\lfloor\arcsin x\rfloor+\lfloor\arccos x\rfloor+\lfloor\arctan x\rfloor =\ln x$$

I believe it has no solution, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: x is between 0 and 1 for all the functions to exist, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Good.  I haven't done this, but the next step would be to look at the function values.  If $0<x\leq1$ then then right-hand side is $\leq0$.  What about the left-hand side?

Comment: Hint: Use the monotony of the inverse trigonometric functions to show that they are positive in the domain $(0, 1]$

Comment: @ryan Solving over $\mathbb{R}$ requires $x\in(0,1]$. In that interval, $\ln x\leq 0$. Consider the values of the inverse trig functions on the LHS.

Comment: This is a problem that can be solved by a short exhaustive search. Since the left side of the equation is an integer, $\ln x$ must be an integer, so
$$
x\in\{ \ldots, e^{-3}, e^{-2}, e^{-1}, e^0=1, e^1, e^2, e^3, \ldots \}.
$$

Notice that since $-1.57\approx-\pi/2 <\arctan x < +\pi/2\approx +1.57, $ and so $\lfloor\arctan x\rfloor \in \{ -2,-1,0,1 \}.$

And $\lfloor \arcsin x \rfloor, \lfloor \arccos x \rfloor \in \{ -2,-1,0,1 \}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

As **@bjoyn93** points out, we need only solve over $(0,1]$. All three functions, $\arcsin x, \arccos x, \arctan x$ are continuous and increasing or decreasing, so we can use this to divide the interval into sub-intervals where the LHS takes particular values. The easiest case is $\arctan x$, which has a range of $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and thus only passes near the three integers $-1,0,1$. In fact, over $(0,1]$, its floor is identically $0$.

When do $\arcsin x, \arccos x$ pass by integers? What constant value would the LHS take between each of these crossing-points?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture over the interval $(0,1]$. I've marked the critical points of the floored inverse trigonometrical functions to better see how this functions behave.

[image]

Simply put, there are three cases:

- $x \in (0, \cos 1]:$ Then $0+1+0=\ln x \Rightarrow x = e \notin (0, \cos 1]$.
- $x \in (\cos 1, \sin 1):$ Then $0+0+0=\ln x\Rightarrow x = 1 \notin (\cos 1, \sin 1)$
- $x \in [\sin 1, 1]:$ Then $1+0+0=\ln x\Rightarrow x = e \notin [\sin 1, 1]$.

In conclusion, no solution.